# Confused about the result of a map

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following:

```
fun getAttendees(): Single<List<Parent>>
fun getChildren(int idOfParent): Single<ChildrenResponse>

ChildrenResponse contains a List<Children>
```

If I subscribe to:

```
getAttendees()
.flatMapObservable { parentList -> Observable.from(parentList) }
.map { parent -> getChildren(parent.id) }
```

Android Studio tells me I get a Single instead of a ChildrenResponse.

My second question is how do I get an observable that returns an aggregated list of all the children(children of parent1 + children of parent2, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You need to flatMap instead of map since getChildren() is a stream. So the updated good would look something like below

```
getAttendees() 
    .flatMapObservable { parentList -> Observable.from(parentList) }
    // Iterate through parentList
    .flatMapIterable{parents -> parents}
    // For each parent get the children and create a pair of <Parent, List<Children>>
    .flatMapSingle { 
        parent -> getChildren(parent.id)
                  //Mapping children to Pair<Parent, List<Children>>
                  .map{children -> Pair.create(parent, children)}
    }
    // Create List<Pair<Parent, List<Children>>>
    .toList()
    .subscribe(
        result -> Get List<Pair<Parent, List<Children>>>,
        error -> //handle error
    );
```

PS: I am not familiar with Rx-kotlin and hence my coding style will be more aligned towards Rx-Java style.